# "the specified file was not found" error on server 2k12 when accesing Network drive

Tags: windows-server-2012

In win server2012 icreate the network drive and create one folder on it i share the folder also now when i am trying to access it it showing the error "the specified file was not found"

Comment: Please can you give us more details in what you are trying to do. At least, we need to know the end result you are trying to reach.

Comment: I have one server Windows server 2012 R2 datacenter i created one drive on it for ex. D:\ i also created the folder on it  ex. D:\data and share it. with full rights to everyone. now when i am trying to access it through one of our tool. tool is doing RDP directly to that drive only. at that time its showing error "the specified file was not found" .

Comment: How are you trying to access this share? From where?

Comment: another all the application working fine with the tool.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Are you trying to access the file from the server?

Comment: no now i am trying to access the file from my client machine.

Comment: ok, so ignore RDP, and try \\<servername>\<sharename> in a run command instead.

also did you set share permissions (from the share tab for folder) as well as NTFS permissions? (from the security tab, for the folder)

Comment: Its accessible through \\<servername>\<drivename>

Comment: but the file your tool needs is not visible?

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions for both the share, and the folder/file in question

Share permissions :-

Access this by Right Click folder that has been shared> properties > Sharing tab > Advanced Sharing.
[image: Sharing image]

Then click 'Permissions'

[image: Share Permissions window]

It is normal practice to allow everyone full permissions to the share.

NTFS (file) permissions :-

Access this by Right Click folder that has been shared> properties > security tab > 'edit' button.

[image]

add a valid domain/local user and ensure that they at **least** have the read and list folder contents permission.

Comment: As per vendor i use the below command                                            
e,/root, e:/userdata/%username%